# Google Maps (API) errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the following javascript to embed a custom google map.

For some reason the website has started coming up with errors. I cannot work out what is happening/what has changed and causing the errors. It seems to point towards the google API but I have tried changing this and the problem still happens.

The website is live at www.ninelivesbar.com if inspecting that helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

              function init() {
                  // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                  // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                  var mapOptions = {
                      // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                      zoom: 15,

                      // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.503560, -0.081678), // Nine Lives

                      // How you would like to style the map. 
                      // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                      styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]
                  };


                  // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                  // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                  var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                  // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
                  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                  // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.503560, -0.081678),
                      map: map,
                      title: 'Snazzy!'
                  });
              }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: this code si based on google maps v3 ..api have a correct link for import the related  js api ????'

Answer (score 0):

You are listening to event coming from your current window before your run your init function... So your map is initialized multiple time... Here is the way I did using javascript to render my map.

```
<script>
  function initialize() {

    // Map initialization goes here

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```